Do echo replies typically send out an ARP request?
When a host receives an ICMP echo message from an unknown IP on the same subnet, would it send an ARP request to determine the IP's associated MAC address? Or would it simply flip the source/dest MAC fields in the ethernet header of the incoming packet and reply?
It seems from this question (ARP table updated when receive message) that the ARP cache is only updated on ARP replies, rather than gaining information from every incoming packet. This makes sense to me, but simply replying to a packet immediately should not require any ARP cache updates.

That would imply that the interface the unknown host uses for receiving is the same one it uses for sending, which is not necessarily true.

If a destination address is not in the ARP table for IPv4 on a data-link protocol that uses MAC addresses, then, yes, it would require an ARP request to resolve the MAC address from the IP address. IP (ICMP is an integral part of IP) has no knowledge of the underlying data-link protocol, so it knows nothing of MAC addresses or ARP.
Remember that the network stack is layered, and there are many different data-link protocols, and IP does not know or care which carries it, nor does the data-link protocol know or care which network protocol is in its payload. Even with something like ethernet that needs ARP for IPv4, ARP is not used for other network protocols. For example, IPv6 on ethernet will use NDP because ARP uses broadcast, but IPv6 does not have broadcast.
Once an IPv4-to-MAC address resoultion is in the ARP cache, it will stay there for a specified time, so an ARP request may not be needed. When a host sends an ICMP echo request, and it needs to send an ARP request, the recipient of that ARP request can use the ARP request to update its ARP table, so it may not need to send an ARP request to be able to reply; it can simply look in its ARP cache.
